# C# Drop Down List Web Form ASP.NET SQL not populating

Tags: c#, sql-server, drop-down-menu

```
protected void CompanyDropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dropdownCompany]", cn);
        cn.Open();
        CompanyDropDown.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        CompanyDropDown.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The stored procedure dropdownCompany is just one column with a list of company names.

For some reason this is not populating the drop down when I execute the web form.

Comment: Have you tried executing the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio to see if there is actually data being returned?

Comment: Yeah the stored procedure populated the results in sql server management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before binding, specify `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` for the dropdown.

`DataTextField` and `DataValueField` should be the name of columns from the result set which you get after executing your stored procedure.

You should specify which field will be visible to the user in the dropdown. This will be your `DataTextField`.

`DataValueField` is not visible to the user. but you will need this value when you are performing some other operation based on the selected item in the dropdown.

```
CompanyDropDown.DataTextField = "Name";
CompanyDropDown.DataValueField = "ID";
CompanyDropDown.DataBind();
```

Comment: this is my sql stored procedure:


    SELECT distinct companyid, companyname from Company

Comment: Did you change the values from `Name` and `ID` to `companyname` and `companyid`?

Comment: Yep:

CompanyDropDown.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                CompanyDropDown.DataTextField = "companyname";
                CompanyDropDown.DataValueField = "companyid";
                CompanyDropDown.DataBind();

Comment: Btw, why is your code in Dropdown's click event? You want the dropdown to be populated when u click on it? Or when the page is loading?

Comment: I want the drop down to be populated when you click on it, but would it make a difference if its when the page is loaded and then the user clicks on it?

Comment: I would try moving this logic to the `Page_Load` event and see what happens

Comment: Are you sure there is click event for a dropdown.. I dont see it.. :/

Comment: it worked in the page_load event. I guess the click event doesn't exist!

Comment: yes.. it works in page load event.. I have tried it on my system. You can add the dropdown logic below the code which you already have.. OR you can put the dropdown logic in a function and call that function from your page_load event.. Dont repeat the SqlConnection part.

Comment: Great! Thanks both

Comment: You're welcome :) Let us know if you come across any issues with your dropdown in future..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `CommandType` property of your `SqlCommand` object to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

```
protected void CompanyDropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dropdownCompany]", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cn.Open();
        CompanyDropDown.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        CompanyDropDown.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this line also:

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;